# Python - Ordering a tuple of dictionaries/nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have attempted to look for similar questions and through the python manual but still have issues understanding how to solve my issue. I have a nested dictionary and I would like to rearrange the key order of the nested dictionary and sort it alphabetically by a column (in this case it would be by hobby).

Nested dictionary: (disability column is empty if client is not disabled)

```
client_info = {amy: {'age': '30', 'hobby': 'travel', 'status': 'relationship', 'disability': 'disabled'}
               john: {'age': '20', 'hobby': 'painting', 'status': 'single', 'disability': ''}
               ...
}
```

I was able to sort hobbies alphabetically with this piece of code which iterates over my keys:

```
with open('AllClients.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    sorted_hobbies = sorted(client_info.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['hobby'])
```

After sorting hobbies alphabetically, my nested dictionary turned into a tuple of dictionaries:

```
[(john, {'age': '20', 'hobby': 'painting', 'status': 'single', 'disability': ''}),
 (amy, {'age': '30', 'hobby': 'travel', 'status': 'relationship', 'disability': 'disabled'})
 ...
]
```

However, after sorting hobbies alphabetically I would like to further change the order of the keys so that the single status column is placed before the hobby column. Ultimately, after all changes I would write it to a csv file in the following format

Desired output:

```
john,20,single,painting,
amy,30,relationship,travel,disabled
```

Apologies if the stuff I've done so far doesn't make sense. I'm having trouble figuring out which direction I should head to achieve the results I need so it's difficult for me to even find the right questions I should be asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting works perfectly for your task. You end up with the list of tuples because `client_info.items()` is a list of tuples. But it is not an issue. Now you can iterate over the resulting list and write data into CSV as you prefer:

```py
...
ordered_hobbies = sorted(client_info.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['hobby'])

for name, data in ordered_hobbies:
    file.write(f"{name},{data['age']},{data['status']},{data['hobby']},{data['disability']}\n")
```

Where `data` would be a dictionary for each client. And you contsruct the CSV line in the order you like (i.e. age, status, hobby, disability)

Comment: I tried what you wrote plus adding a newline and it output correctly to csv, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy that it worked. Will update the answer with a newline.